# Probability Notation: What does $\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$ mean?

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

In the book [Stats with Julia](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/YoniNazarathy/julia-stats/StatisticsWithJulia.pdf) on p. 79 is reads ...

> "The probability distribution of a random variable fully describes the
>   probabilities of the events such as $\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$ for all sensible $A \subset R$"

How would you say "$\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$" in plain English?

Is it ....

for every possible outcome $(\omega)$ in the $(\in)$ event space $(\Omega)$ such that $(:)$ there is some specific outcome $(X(\omega))$ in the set $A$ where set $A$ contains real numbers

.. is that close??

Comment: why are you saying "for every"? this is a set of certain $\omega$. it is the set of outcomes in the event space such that the random variable takes value in $A$ on that outcome

Comment: Use MathJax for formatting math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit] Yeah. The way to see, is to look to $X$ being a function (random variable).  $$X: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$
The subset $A\subset \Bbb R$ is just to know what values can be and restrict the events $\omega\in \Omega$.

Comment: Thanks. What does the colon mean please?

Comment: I don’t agree with the last line you’ve mentioned. “if you want all the events of omega that only have greater or equal to 90% chance occurring can be described by ________”. To describe it correctly you need to define a “sigma-algebra” and a Probability Measure.

Comment: It is a notation to describe a set. You can read it like _such as_ somenthing. Normally, a set is given by all the elements that lives on a bigger set SUCH satisfy some property. 

I recomend you to see some inital set theory to a better explanation. You will see stuffs like $\{x\in X : P(x)\}$, i.e., all the elements of $X$ wich holds the property $P$. Like the even numbers is given by $\{n \in \mathbb{Z} : 2\mid n\}$. The property here is $P(n) = 2\mid n$, "2 divides $n$".

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Sure, sure. But i think that the discussion are more about the notation, so i was trying to give an exemple to ilustrate. That preciosity and rigour's do not are needed to the point here (im my opinion). But sure, we would need  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},X)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is an $\sigma$-algebra and $X$ satisfy _Kolmogorov condictions_.

Comment: You're still not correct $X(\omega)$ does NOT represent the probability of event $\omega$ happening. $X(\omega)$ is just a function to the real line. It can take any real number.

Comment: Please correct or remove the false statement that $X(\omega)$ represents the probability that $\omega$ occurs. Take any non-unit interval $[a, b]$ say with $1<a<b$ and define $X(\omega)=\omega$. Then the values of $X(\omega)$ cannot represent probabilities, while the events $\omega\in (a, x]$ have chance $\omega/(b-a)$. Further, normally distributed random variable can take on *negative values* making your statement even more nonsensical.

Answer (score 9):

We have

- $\Omega$ = outcome space.
- $\omega$ = a particular outcome (that is, $\omega \in \Omega$).
- If $Z$ is an *event* then it is a *subset* of $\Omega$ (that is, $Z \subseteq \Omega)$. (*See footnote for an additional detail.)

Indeed the random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $A$ is some given subset of real numbers.  Then the following is a subset of $\Omega$: 
$$  \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\} $$
We interpret this as:

\begin{align} 
\{\cdot\} \quad  &= \quad \mbox{"The set of ..."}\\
\omega \in \Omega \quad &= \quad \mbox{"outcomes $\omega$ in the outcome space $\Omega$...}" \\
: \quad &= \quad \mbox{"such that..."}\\
X(\omega) \in A \quad  &= \quad \mbox{"$X(\omega)$ is in the set $A$"}
\end{align}

Put all together  it reads:

**The set of outcomes $\omega$ in the outcome space $\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)$ is in the set $A$.**

Notice that 
$$ \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\} \subseteq \Omega$$

---

Example: 
\begin{align}
\Omega &= \{blue, red, green, pink\}\\
X(blue) &= 2\\
X(red) &= 2.5\\
X(green) &=0\\
X(pink) &=-3\\
A &= \{2, -3, 8\}\\
B &= \{2.5, 0, -3\}\\
C &= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x\leq 1\} = (-\infty, 1]
\end{align}
Then 
\begin{align}
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\} &= \{blue, pink\}\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} &= \{red, green, pink\}\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in C\} &= \: ??? \quad \quad [\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A \cap B\} &= \: ???\quad \quad [\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \notin A\} &= \: ???\quad \quad [\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) > 0\} &= \: ??? \quad \quad[\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq 0\} &= \: ??? \quad \quad[\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq 100\} &= \: ??? \quad \quad[\mbox{Exercise}]\\
\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq -78\} &= \: ??? \quad \quad[\mbox{Exercise}]
\end{align}

How many possible events are there (for this example)?

Comment: *An additional property of _events_ is that, not only are they subsets of $\Omega$, but they are in a pre-specified collection of such subsets that form a "sigma algebra."   If $\Omega$ is a finite or countably infinite set then it is easiest to just assume the sigma algebra is the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$. Then all subsets of $\Omega$ are events,  and so $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$ is indeed an _event_.

Comment: But what is A in your case? You never defined it.

Comment: The asker Axle never defined the set $A$, presumably it is a given subset of real numbers.  In my specific example I gave a specific set $A$.  I have modified my answer above to emphasize that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ also in the first part.

Comment: So we can use $X^{-1}(A)$ notation?

Comment: You could, indeed by definition $$X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$$